# Tailwind doesn't build with @apply classes and forces mobile-like viewport

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

got a weird issue, gonna try to explain it as well as I can.

So, sometimes when coding my React project with Tailwind (bundled with Vite), Tailwind just decides to stop working. It compiles only the classes used by my component library - that being Flowbite - but not any other other ones.. here's my `input.css` - the file looks like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
    .filtry_nadpis {
        @apply mt-4 mb-2 text-xl font-extrabold leading-none tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-2xl lg:text-3xl dark:text-white;
    }
}
```

Here's how it looks in the browser when it breaks:
[broken website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoGZF.png)

The text at the top should has the `.filtry_nadpis` class, and the whole page should be 70% of the screen. It just looks like on mobile - even the number of columns in the shop are like on mobile - not according to the actual viewport width.

I always fixed this by going back a commit in git - this time, it didn't work. It breaks seemingly randomly.

Note this was happening before & after I started using Vite.

Tried deleting node modules and reinstalling, rebuilding Tailwind, restarting the server... But to na avail.

*Edit:*
Config files:
tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    safeList: [],
    content: [
      './index.html',
      './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts}',
      "node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    tailwindcss()
  ],
});
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Comment: Interesting. mind posting the tailwind.config, vite.config and postcss.config files? to rule out any issues there

Comment: Added config files.

Comment: And you just use tailwindcss in .js files not .jsx correct?

Comment: In jsx. Fixed the config, but it didn't help.

Comment: i just checked the geting started page from flowbite react and it says in content you need to add 'node_modules/flowbite-react/lib/esm/**/*.js' i never used flowbite but have you tried that? and update the config file in the question with the updated config file and inside the vite.config you are missing in the plugins section postcss()

Comment: Updated the configs... Still doesn't work. Same issue.

Comment: try updating the configs in the question with the current version so that maybe someone else can help

Comment: Okay, updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I'm dumb as a brick. Fixed it by adding jsx files in my Tailwing config.